# Find a function so whenever it is near a lattice point $\lim_{x \rightarrow [x_0]}f(x)=[y_0]$

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions, integer-lattices

A function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an "easy estimator" if any point on $f$, $(x_0,y_0)$, is near a lattice point $([x_0],[y_0])$  then  $\lim_{x \rightarrow [x_0]}f(x)=[y_0]$.

In other words:

If for any $(x_0,y_0)$ on $f(x)$ where we have $\sqrt{(y_0-[y_0])^2+(x_0 - [x_0])^2} \leq \delta$ then it is also the case that $f([x_0])=[y_0]$

[image: this is a function that works for the given delta]

[image: this one fails.]

**Example of an "easy" easy estimator:**

$f(x)=x$

$f(x)=x$ is an easy esitmator because if $(x,y)$ is close to $([x],[y])$ then $([x],[y])$ satisfies $f(x)=y$.

Questions.

1. What is the largest possible $\delta$ for $f(x)=x$?
2. What is the largest possible $\delta$ for any $f$?
3. How about some more examples? Especially non-linear functions?

Comment: By the way what notation would you use?

Comment: $f (x) = x+ \sin (\pi x)$ (for example) works if $\delta < ~.26$ for $f (x) = 100\sin (\pi x)+ x$ we need $\delta < ~.004$  because it is close to (‐1,0) but it will not pass through (‐1,0) ... So I dont think that works.

Comment: But what I've said is that $\lim_{x \rightarrow [x]} f(x) = [f(x)]$

Comment: $\lim_{x \rightarrow [x_0]}f(x)=[f(x_0)]$ is that better?

Comment: That's what I wrote. But thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I did not see your comment. In any case thanks for the input. I thought your example was for all c.

Comment: I think you have been very helpful. I didn't notice the error that you pointed out. Do you still think the question is flawed?

Comment: @Did It's plausible that futurebird edited [his/her comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232163/find-a-function-so-whenever-it-is-near-a-lattice-point-lim-x-rightarrow-x-0#comment2520212_1232163) (at least, started editing it) before you posted yours. And I'm pretty confident that "I did not see your comment" means the reasonable "... before editing mine [that is, futurebird's] above it" here, not the ridiculous "... at all".

Comment: @DanielFischer It is plausible that futurebird has been unable to reach a sensible question for 5 days and that they responded to my tries to make them reach one by accusing me of condescension. It is plausible that I have been the only user so far to try to help the OP and that for this I have been insulted by them and chastised by a mod. So be it. Let now the multitude of users more helpful to this OP than I could ever be, enter the scene.

Comment: @Did I wasn't chastising you, that would read differently. Just pointing out that the sequence of events may have been less unfavourable. Is it really so hard to believe that you pointing out a flaw in the question made the OP understand that flaw and enabled him/her to correct it?

Comment: Oops... no more "condescension" comment. So convenient.

Comment: Why the down votes and the multitude of deleted comments? Sometimes the immaturity on this site surprises me. I want to investigate this problem, so I'd appreciate  some motivation for this question. I'll give it a try either way though ;).

Comment: What do the square brackets mean in this question?

Comment: Tommi that is the nearest integer function.

Answer (score 2):

Consider thre finite sequences of integers $(p_n)_{1\leq n\leq N}$, $(q_n)_{1\leq n\leq N}$ and $(a_n)_{1\leq n\leq N}$, such that for all $n$ $q_n\neq0$  and, without loss of generality, $p_n\wedge q_n=1$. Then the function $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N \left\lvert \frac{p_n}{q_n} x-a_n\right\rvert\tag{1}$$ 
satisfies your requirements. The graph of $f$ has an irregular sawtooth shape. It is easy to see that the slope of $f$ takes the values
$$\frac pq=\sum_{n=1}^N\epsilon_n\left\lvert\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right\rvert,$$ 
where $\epsilon_n=0$ or $1$.

The minimal distance between a line of slope $\frac pq$ and a point of integer coordinates that does not belong is the value of $\delta$ for this $f$ : $$\delta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{p^2+q^2}}.\tag{2}$$
So $\delta(f)$ is the maximum of expression (2) for all possible choices of $(\epsilon_n)$.